# Flutter how to handle image with fixed size inside box?

Tags: image, layout, flutter, containers

I am new to Flutter and I like it but I am not comfortable building layouts.

I am working on an app that contains a ListView of Cards.
Each card is inside a Container and contains an image (with fixed height and width) and a text.

I am not able to place the image correctly inside the Card. I want the image to cover the width of box.
Thanks.

[image]

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'MyApp';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                    margin:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
                        child: InkWell(
                           onTap: () => print("ciao"),     
                           child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                    ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                        topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                      ),
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        'img/britannia.jpg',
                                        width: 300,
                                        height: 150,
                                        fit:BoxFit.fill  

                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text('Pub 1'),
                                      subtitle: Text('Location 1'),
                                    ),
                                ],
                           ),
                        ),
                    ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Each card has a fixed size` - what is the Fixed Size .?

Comment: Each Container  has to be (for example) 150 height.
What i want is scale the image according to height of Container (Container contains the card).
I wish to show the image like first pic, despite source image dimensions.

Comment: Have you tried using the Expanded class? https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Comment: I have updated the code and the image. I have to wrap the Image widget or ClipRRect widget inside Expanded?

Comment: how to fit small image in big container in flutter ? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 61):

You need to add - `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` in `Column` so that children can take up horizontal space.

Working Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'MyApp';

return MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
    ),
    body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => print("ciao"),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,  // add this
                children: <Widget>[
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Image.network(
                        'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
                       // width: 300,
                        height: 150,
                        fit:BoxFit.fill

                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Pub 1'),
                    subtitle: Text('Location 1'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => print("ciao"),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Image.network(
                        'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
                        // width: 300,
                        height: 150,
                        fit:BoxFit.fill

                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Pub 1'),
                    subtitle: Text('Location 1'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => print("ciao"),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Image.network(
                        'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
                        // width: 300,
                        height: 150,
                        fit:BoxFit.fill

                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Pub 1'),
                    subtitle: Text('Location 1'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: how to fit small image in big container in flutter ? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

I don't know how.. But this really worked to keep image with fixed size in container
Just add Alignment in container

```dart
    Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      alignment: Alignment.center, // This is needed
      child: Image.asset(
        Constants.ASSETS_IMAGES + "logo.png",
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        width: 300,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Alignment strangely solved my problem too

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me

```
Image.network(imageUrl, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
```

Answer (score 19):

Put Image widget inside container and give alignment center to container and specific width-height to the image.

```js
return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,// use aligment
      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 96, 91, 1),
      child: Image.asset('assets/images/splash_logo.png',
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
      fit: BoxFit.cover),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, The alignment part i was missing

Answer (score 9):

```
 Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/desert.jpg',
                  height: 150,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  fit:BoxFit.cover

              )
```

Answer (score 7):

```
child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,// use aligment
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/call.png',
                height: 45,
                width: 45,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
```

**Use this if you want with border**

```
            Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 75),
            width: 120,
            height: 120,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/call.png",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 45,
              width: 45,
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(120)),
              border: new Border.all(
                color: Colors.blue,
                width: 4.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this and worked fine with me!

```
  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 175,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: NetworkImage(YOUTUBE_THUMBNAIL_PART_ONE +
                            video.key +
                            YOUTUBE_THUMBNAIL_PART_TWO),
                      ),
                    )),
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is probably use the size of the bigger container.
In that case your media should occupy the whole dedicate space:

```
return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Image.asset(
        '', //TODO fill path
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
```

You can play with the `fit` value:

- `BoxFit.cover` will cover the whole container
- `BoxFit.fitWidth` will fit the width and eventually put horizontal white bars to fill the space
- `BoxFit.fitHeight` will fit the height and eventually put vertical white bars to fill the space

Answer (score 4):

All you need is `fit` property of `Image` class:

```dart
Image.asset(
  'your_image_asset',
  fit: BoxFit.fill, // Expands to fill parent (changes aspect ratio)
)
```

or

```dart
Image.asset(
  'your_image_asset',
  fit: BoxFit.cover, // Zooms the image (maintains aspect ratio)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If doable with the fit property, I let this very clear cheat sheet (chapter fit Property) detail everything: https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-boxdecoration-cheat-sheet-72cedaa1ba20

Comment: Would you like to fit the witdh ?? Then `fitWidth` should do the trick, no ??

Comment: But why are you putting an height and width to your image ?? Then you won't have the desire effect... You should define the height to you `card` widget

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I just added in the Image.asset class the                                         fit:BoxFit.fill after using the MediaQuery class to get the width of the screen**

```
    Container(
              child:Image.asset(link,fit: BoxFit.fill,)
              width: screensize.width,
              height: 150,
            ))
```

Comment: there is no `fit` property in `Container` widget

Comment: @KirillKarmazin I just noticed the mistake I made. I edited my answer, now it should work. Thanks fo noticing.

Answer (score 1):

Sample;

```
Image.asset(
                        'assets/img/premium_user.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        height: 20,
                      ),
```

Then set preferred height.

Answer (score 0):

1. crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
2. fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
3. width: double.infinity, height: 100,

Example:

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Image.network(userinfo.avatar ?? '',
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => Image.asset(
              'assets/niko_huh.png',
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 100,
            )),
```