# Flutter image in container look streched

Tags: flutter, flutter-image, flutter-container

When I try to place an image in container with specific height the image look stretched please find the below screenshot. Is it possible to fit the image as actual image without stretching.

[image]

actual image

[image]

```
Container(
                  height: 350,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                    boxShadow: const [BoxShadow(color: Color.fromRGBO(104, 104, 104, 0.2), offset: Offset(0, 1), spreadRadius: 5, blurRadius: 10)],
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      //colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1.0), BlendMode.color),
                      image: getImage(imageId: 123).image,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to handle image with fixed size inside box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885879/flutter-how-to-handle-image-with-fixed-size-inside-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fit: BoxFit.contain,` or `fit: BoxFit.cover,`

if you are use BoxFit.cover
you can alignment use to align the image

```
fit: BoxFit.cover,
alignment: Alignment.topCenter,,
```

---

[image: fit: BoxFit.contain]

```
fit: BoxFit.contain,
```

---

[image: fit: BoxFit.contain,alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,]

```
fit: BoxFit.contain,
alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
```

---

[image: fit: BoxFit.contain, alignment: Alignment.topCenter,]

```
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
```

---